# Selenium Python: Loading Non-Default Chrome Profiles is Not Working

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, profile

My code so far is short and sweet.

```
    # creates an options for chrome
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--user-data-dir = /Users/user/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/")
    options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 1")
```

However, it won't ever use "Profile 1" as my profile. In fact, it won't even use the same "Default" profile every time either. Whenever I go to chrome://version, it gives me a random path.
An example of that would be

```
   /private/var/folders/td/zj1v269x7yvgmzxmjzbr4j1h0000gn/T/.com.google.Chrome.RXJ0oZ/Profile 1
```

I have tried a number of things, including running my program without any other chrome instances. I made the profile on my normal chrome browser, not the driver. Not sure if that matters too much but I even tried to create a test account with them both to no prevail.

I am pretty good in C++, so if someone could help me and could be kind enough to explain it in relationship to C++, I would be appreciative.

Comment: Copy the profile directory to your project directory and then provide the full path

Comment: @ThePyGuy I have done that, but it seems to still be assinging random profiles. No matter what I name the profile, Profile 1, Panda, Triangle, it will create a profile in a random folder with the name. Kind of like the above example. Once I implemented your suggestion, a chrome pop up would come up, it was asking me to create a new profile every time I launched the program.